# PC screen is black. What to do?

Tags: login

I left my Ubuntu machine without touching it for some time. Usually then I move the mouse and enter my password and continue.

I do not know if it is relevant, but this time I pressed by mistake <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, then moved the mouse to get the login screen.

But now, the screen is black (except for an arrow for the mouse, but the mouse is not responsive) and I cannot login.

The PC is working furiously (I can hear the fan).
What can I do to get the login screen? (other than just restart the PC)

Comment: Did you try to type the password and press Enter, even if you don't see a password field? Some lockers work like that, for example, i3lock.

Comment: This is happening again. Any news?